# wget or curl to download .app file that has been zipped from github

Tags: bash, curl, github

app file that I have zipped up and pushed to a github project of mine.

Now i want to write a bash script to download this zipped file, however I can't seem wget to work.

I am doing wget

```
https://github.com/MyProject/myRepo/blob/master/appBuild/myApp.zip?raw=true -O /Users/myName/Desktop/myApp.zip
```

but I get some corrupted file

Comment: Add output of `file /Users/myName/Desktop/myApp.zip` to your question.

Comment: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/project/branch/path/to/file.zip`

Answer (score 0):

On my github repo, I have been using wget to download the main archive.
Try this for you:

```
wget https://github.com/MyProject/myRepo/blob/master/appBuild/myApp.zip -O /Users/myName/Desktop/myApp.zip
```

I simply removed the "?raw=true" from the link. I haven't used that flag before.

If you can provide me the actual link, I'd be happy to test it for you.

Comment: It's a private repo unfortunately, but removing the ?raw=true does not help. In both cases I get myApp.zip on my desktop, and when I try to unzip it I get myApp.zip.cpgz which is not myApp.app

Comment: @user3735746 a "cpgz" is another archive like "zip". Do you have 7-Zip installed? Try extracting it with that utility.